# Save data and hide ASP.NET Gridview row after button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm creating reservation application in ASP.NET,C#. 
I have a gridview with an asp.net button that calls a C# method to update a database based on some data within the gridview row.

How to hide the row on button click and save data ?

Source code:

**aspx**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  HorizontalAlign="Center" AllowPaging="True" CellPadding="3" Width="568px"  GridLines="Vertical" Visible="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px">       

        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#121315" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />  

           <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />

      <Columns>          

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HALL">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HallGroupID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ShowSeatID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ShowSeatID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="COLOR">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Color") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Color") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PRICE">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Price") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Price") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>  

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ROW">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SeatRow") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SeatRow") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField> 

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NUMBER">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SeatNumber") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SeatNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>               

           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="STATUS" SortExpression="Active">
                    <ItemTemplate><%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("IsReserved").ToString())) ? "RESERVED" : "FREE" %></ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>            

            <asp:TemplateField>                  
                <ItemTemplate>                        
                   <asp:Button ID="ButtonReserve" style="background:#2ACC16; border-radius:8px;" runat="server" CommandName="Reserve" HeaderText="BOOK SEAT" Text="Reserve" OnClick="ButtonReserve_Click" />                
                </ItemTemplate>            
             </asp:TemplateField> 

       </Columns>                      
   </asp:GridView>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void ButtonReserve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gvr = ((Button)sender).Parent.Parent as GridViewRow;
    Label hallID = (Label)gvr.FindControl("Label1");     
    Label seatID = (Label)gvr.FindControl("Label3");
    Label color = (Label)gvr.FindControl("Label4");
    Label price = (Label)gvr.FindControl("Label5");
    Label seatRow = (Label)gvr.FindControl("Label6");
    Label seatNumber = (Label)gvr.FindControl("Label7");

    Label7.Text = hallID.Text;       
    Label9.Text = seatID.Text;
    Label10.Text = color.Text;
    Label11.Text = price.Text;
    Label12.Text = seatRow.Text;
    Label13.Text = seatNumber.Text;

}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  `GridViewRow`, like any other web UI control, has a `.Visible` property that you can set.

Comment: Please put all your grid code here, if you can....

Comment: I tried add ButtonReserve.Visible = false; but shows error : The name does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Added all grid code as  jitendra joshi suggested

Comment: Adding example how it looks : http://s31.postimg.org/if1j36znf/Untitled.jpg

Comment: use find control also for ButtonReserve then try visible = false

Comment: How to use find control in my code?

Comment: simple... like other lables.......Button ButtonReserve = (Button)gvr.FindControl("ButtonReserve");

Comment: Thanks! It worked. That was really simple.

Comment: I suggest using `((Button)sender).NamingContainer` instead of `((Button)sender).Parent.Parent`.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you don't hide the row.

You would make the update and rebind the GridView.

Depending on your needs, the row would either be excluded from the dataset or included and marked up in some way as to represent it's new "updated" state.